# Un-gzipping MRI Files in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, gunzip, matlab-spm

I'm learning MATLAB +SPM12 to do structural MRI analysis. To do this, I need to change the format of the files from gz to NIFTI. The guide I'm using said to use

```
gunzip('*.gz')
Flanker=gunzip('*.gz')
Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.

Error in gunzip (line 71)
       destinationIsSameAsSource = ismember(fullfile({entries.file}), fullfile(rootDir,outputDir,files));
```

I tried many different fixes from a google search

```
gunzip('sub-08.gz')
gunzip('sub-08.gz')
>> gunzip('sub-08', '*.gz')
 unzip('sub-08_T1w.nii.gz','Sub-08')`
```

None of these worked for various reasons
sub-08 is the name of the folder trying to unzip.

Comment: How do I pass the names? I looked at the resource and it seems to say can just put down the folder name and will pull out files to be unzipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I give `gunzip('*.gz')` in a directory without any `.gz` files, I get the same error you are reporting ("Dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type"). This looks to be a bug in MATLAB, it should give a more informative error message.

If you give that command in a directory that does have `.gz` files, it works as documented. You can also give the path to the files, for example

```
gunzip('sub-08/*.gz')
```

Or, as [Mark Adler said in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76575984/7328782), you can just give the name of the directory, MATLAB will find the `.gz` files in it automatically. This is not documented though (or if it is, it's not clear enough).

```
gunzip('sub-08')
```

Note that in these examples `sub-08` is a directory under the current directory and contains files with a `.gz` extension.

You can type `pwd` or `cd` to figure out what the current directory is, and `cd('path')` to change the current directory.

If unsure, you can use the `gunzip` command with full path:

```
gunzip('\home\kylee\mri\sub-08\*.gz') % (or whatever path you have of course)
```

Comment: Note that if there are also *.gz files in a sub-directory of `sub-08`, but you only want to decompress the ones at the top level of `sub-08`, then you would need to use `gunzip('sub-08/*.gz')`. Otherwise you can use `gunzip('sub-08')`.

Answer (score 1):

If `sub-08` is a folder that contains gzip files, then use `res = gunzip('sub-08')` to extract all of them, including those in sub-sub-folders. `res` will be a list of the filenames of the uncompressed files.

Comment: The documentation does not support this, but I tried it and it works.

Comment: I didn't know the answer until I looked at the documention! It says exactly this. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gunzip.html

Comment: It says "gzipfilenames — Names of the GNU zip files to extract from, specified as a character vector, a cell array of character vectors, or a string array. File names must include a path relative to the current folder or an absolute path." It doesn't say "names of directories under which to find gzip files".

Comment: You have to read the whole thing. "`gunzip(gzipfilenames)` extracts the archived contents of each file _in_ `gzipfilenames` to the folder containing `gzipfilenames`", and "`gunzip` recursively extracts the content in _folders_". (My emphases.)